# Rollback to the existing packages during EA Server deployment

Tags: powerbuilder, easerver

how to save the existing packages and services in EA Server(Powerbuilder) and to again deploy the saved packages for production deployment rollback?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used EAServer in several years so the details are fuzzy.

In the repository where the .pbd files are located, they are in versioned folders. The text file with component properties has the current version number. You can modify the property in the EA Manager app to point to a different version number.

Just wondering, what version of EAServer do you have? The only install image I have is 5.5 but I can't install it on Windows 10. I'd like to get a developers copy installed on Windows 10. If you have a link to download a Windows 10 compatible version, please post it here.

Comment: Hi Roland,Thanks for the comments.I am using EAServer 5.2 version.Is that is possible in 5.2?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a possible EAServer replacement. If you are interested in being a tester, let me know.

Comment: I would like to know how you are replacing your EA Server because i am also looking to get rid of EA Server from our project?